# how to create thumbnail from http reply image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html page I have  link that leads to a non static image (drawn according to the url query params).

How can I create a thumbnail of this image?

when a user clicks the thumbnail a new page with the large image will open (or the in the same page, doesn't matter).

Is it possible to control the thumbnail to be cropped or zoomed out?

I saw this example, but this assume I have static and locally stored images. No?

```
<A HREF="paperboy.gif"><IMG SRC="pb1.gif"></A>
```

Comment: Point the `src` of the `<img>`, and the `href` of the `<a>`, elements to the same URL (with the same query parameters).

Comment: but then if I want to control the cropping and zoom of the thumbnail?

Comment: If someone clicks that `<a>` element, what should happen? Should the user go to the image (held at the URL), or should the image open up full-screen on the same page?

Comment: both are good. How do i achieve each of them? 
i want to control the thumbnail to be cropped or zoomed out.

Comment: Then you need to update your question to specify exactly *how*, in what way and to what extent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick little jQuery plugin I just whipped up for this.. keep in mind it is not a proper thumbnail - it is still the original image just scaled.

This will not work on older versions of IE.

Alter the `zoom`, `top` and `left` to change the crop size.

http://jsfiddle.net/fyg042m4/1/

**HTML**

```
<a class="thumbify" href="http://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2014/10/21/489485/b807c2282ab0a491bd5c5c1051c6d312.jpg"></a>
```

**JQ Plugin**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.thumbify = function(opts) {
        var url = this.attr('href');
        var $thumb = $('<div class="thumbnail"></div>');

        $thumb.css({
            'background': 'url('+url+')',
            'width': opts.width+'px',
            'height': opts.height+'px',
            'background-size': (opts.width * opts.zoom)+'px ' + (opts.height * opts.zoom)+'px',
            'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
            'background-position': opts.left +'px ' + opts.top +'px'
        });

        this.append($thumb);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.thumbify').thumbify({
        width: '150',
        height: '100',
        zoom: 2.5,
        top: -50,
        left: -40
    });
});
```